# minGW (with g++ 4.7.1) not compiling simple C++11 code (under WinVista)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, windows-vista, mingw32

I did my homework and searched for an answer here and on the net. The simple code below is not compiling:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from thread " << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(hello);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

It's very simple code, but I'm getting the following errors:

```
Thread_Cpp11_002.cpp: In function 'int main()'
Thread_Cpp11_002.cpp:14:5: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
Thread_Cpp11_002.cpp:14:17: error: expected ';' before 't1'
Thread_Cpp11_002.cpp:15:5: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope
```

And I've tried a lot of things, none of which have worked:

1. Declaring `t1` using `thread` instead of `std::thread`
2. Compiling with g++ 4.8.0
3. Using the following flags, individually and together: `-pthread`, `-std=gnu++11`, `-std=c++0x`, `-std=c++11...`

So, I think this question it worth being posted here.

These compilation were done through the command line. After I have it working I will try with Code::Blocks 12.11, which worked fine for C++98.

Remember, I'm using Windows Vista.

Comment: No error about a missing `#include`?

Comment: what arguments do you pass to the compiler? it should have -std=c++11 in it.

Comment: @zneak, I also tried to change using "thread.h" or <thread.h>, in both cases the compilation neiher initiated (no such file).

Comment: @Elazar, Yes I passed: g++ -std=c++11 -o ...

Comment: @ajmacedo, and `-pthread` ?

Comment: Yes, I saw this hint here in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known issue with some builds of MinGW (just search for `mingw thread` in your [favorite engine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mingw+std%3A%3Athread)). If you need thread support, you have to use another library (such as boost or the native Windows API) or a different build.

Comment: I've been tried for the last 3 hours... and fail! I'm near of giving up. I read various related posts, it seems I'll have to study more and more about compilers, while I was just wanting to try C++11. Unfortunatelly, I use Vista thet is not eligible to MSVC 2012 Express, that has C++11 features.

Comment: @ajmecedo: that's why @jerry mentioned `boost`.  boost provides `thread` for pre c++-11 compilers like Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @ajmacedo I can't vouch for it for it, but apparently http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/64-bit/threads-posix/seh/ supports C++11 threads. If you choose to go with boost, its website is http://www.boost.org/.